# a list of several tuples, how to extract the same of the first two elements in the small tuple in the large tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have got a List of tuples of tuples like below:

```py
x = [
    (('102', '393', 'abc'), 63),
    (('102', '393', 'ack'), 8),
    (('117', '393', 'bcx'), 57),
    (('390', '393', 'wff'), 41),
    (('393', '102', 'wer'), 40),
    (('393', '102', 'wfv'), 78),
    (('393', '117', 'iyy'), 7),
    (('393', '448', 'wec'), 25),
]
```

and I am trying to extract the tuples wherein " (('102', '393', 'abc'), 63) and "(('102', '393', 'ack'), 8)," in a same small list

So the output should be

```py
[
  [ (('102', '393', 'abc'), 63), (('102', '393', 'ack'), 8)],
  [ (('117', '393', 'bcx'), 57)],
  [ (('390', '393', 'wff'), 41)],
  [ (('393', '102', 'wer'), 40), (('393', '102', 'wfv'), 78)],
  [ (('393', '117', 'iyy'), 7)],
  [ (('393', '448', 'wec'), 25)]
]
```

I am trying to execute it in python with bubble_sort. I tried this

```py
for i in range(1, len(x)):
    for j in range(0, len(x)):
        if x[j][0] == x[j + 1][0] and x[j][1] == x[j + 1][1]:
            pass
```

However, it's not working.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a complete example of the code that is not working. The current code won't really do anything. The example you have provided looks more like grouping then sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try by using a defaultdict/dict:

```
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

x = [
    (('102', '393', 'abc'), 63),
    (('102', '393', 'ack'), 8),
    (('117', '393', 'bcx'), 57),
    (('390', '393', 'wff'), 41),
    (('393', '102', 'wer'), 40),
    (('393', '102', 'wfv'), 78),
    (('393', '117', 'iyy'), 7),
    (('393', '448', 'wec'), 25),
]

val = defaultdict(list)

for item in x: 
    val[item[0][0], item[0][1]].append(item)

pprint(list(val.values()))
```

output:

```
[[(('102', '393', 'abc'), 63), (('102', '393', 'ack'), 8)],
 [(('117', '393', 'bcx'), 57)],
 [(('390', '393', 'wff'), 41)],
 [(('393', '102', 'wer'), 40), (('393', '102', 'wfv'), 78)],
 [(('393', '117', 'iyy'), 7)],
 [(('393', '448', 'wec'), 25)]]
```

if you want to take only the second element from each list item, after the above processing :

```
pprint([[e[1] for e in i] for i in val.values()])
```

output:

```
[[63, 8], [57], [41], [40, 78], [7], [25]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)):

```
x = [
    (('102', '393', 'abc'), 63),
    (('102', '393', 'ack'), 8),
    (('117', '393', 'bcx'), 57),
    (('390', '393', 'wff'), 41),
    (('393', '102', 'wer'), 40),
    (('393', '102', 'wfv'), 78),
    (('393', '117', 'iyy'), 7),
    (('393', '448', 'wec'), 25),
]

from itertools import groupby

out = [[*g] for _, g in groupby(x, lambda k: (k[0][0], k[0][1]))]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[(('102', '393', 'abc'), 63), (('102', '393', 'ack'), 8)],
 [(('117', '393', 'bcx'), 57)],
 [(('390', '393', 'wff'), 41)],
 [(('393', '102', 'wer'), 40), (('393', '102', 'wfv'), 78)],
 [(('393', '117', 'iyy'), 7)],
 [(('393', '448', 'wec'), 25)]]
```

Comment: I'm sorry I want to ask another question again. If I just want to get the numbers out, how could I do?   like this,[ [63, 8], [57], [40, 78], [41],[40, 78], [7],[25]] or [[63, 8], [40, 78], I'm soryy, my question is a little more.

Comment: This solution will not work as expected if x it is not sorted, luckily, x it is sorted